# ¿Como hacer una consulta con variables SQL en Query Builder ORM de Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, querybuilder

Esta consulta funciona bien en phpMyAdmin que refleja el saldo acumulado

```
SET @acumulador=0;
SELECT 
    concepto, 
    cargo, 
    abono, 
    @acumulador:=(cargo - abono + @acumulador) AS saldo 
FROM poliza_detalles 
WHERE cuenta_id = 1
```

Pero ¿como hacer esa consulta en Query Builder ORM de Laravel?

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
->select('tp.descripcion', 'pd.cuenta_id', 'pd.concepto', 'pd.cargo', 'pd.abono')
        ->where('pd.cuenta_id', '=', 1)
        ->groupBy('pd.id')
        ->get();
```

Vista:

```
@foreach ($auxBancos as $aux)

            @php
                $saldo = $aux->cargo - $aux->abono
            @endphp

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $aux->concepto }}</td>
                <td>{{ $aux->cargo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $aux->abono }}</td>
                <td>{{ $saldo }} </td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

Me muestra el siguiente resultado, que no es lo que quiero:

```
CARGO  ABONO  SALDO
100     0     100
 0      50    -50
 0     10     -10
30      0      30
```

Lo que yo espero:

```
CARGO   ABONO    SALDO
100       0       100
  0      50        50
  0      10        40
 30       0        70
```

Comment: Creo que tu fórmula debería ser $saldo = $saldo + cargo - abono

Comment: Aclaranos por favor tu fórmula para poder proponerte una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @acumulador=0'));

DB::table('poliza_detalles')
    ->select([
        'tp.descripcion',
        'pd.cuenta_id',
        'pd.concepto',
        'pd.cargo',
        'pd.abono',
        DB::raw('@acumulador:=(cargo - abono + @acumulador) AS saldo')
    ])
    ->where('pd.cuenta_id', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

**PD:** Deberías sacar de la vista el calculo del `saldo`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, ya quedo resuelto